# Install capyabara-webkit gem on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, qt5, capybara-webkit, amazon-linux

I am trying to [install the capybara-webkit gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#debian--ubuntu) on Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09.

I tried following the [install instructions for CentOS](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#centos-7) (maybe the wrong approach):

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y qt5-qtwebkit-devel
```

The first package installed fine, but `qt5-qtwebkit-devel` gave the following error:

```
Error: Package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.6.1-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.6.1-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.6.1-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.6.1-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am unable to resolve the `libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0` dependency in Amazon Linux. I tried installing `libX11-devel` but that did not resolve the issue.

Of course `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.10.1'` fails because qt5 is not installed.

I found a [blog with instructions for installing capybara with qt-4.8](http://blog.smart.ly/2013/11/11/headless-integration-testing-capybara-webkit/), I would rather use the latest version and would prefer to use a package manager instead of compiling the package manually.

My question is, how can I install capybara-webkit on Amazon Linux AMI using the package managers?

Comment: Did you ever get this working with amazon linux? I am encountering the same.

Comment: No.  I have not got it working yet.  I used an Ubuntu server for my capyabara work.

Comment: See if this helps https://ubunifu.co/python/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-amazon-linux-ami-2017-03-1

Comment: @TarunLalwani.  That actually helped a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon AMI doesn’t have a yum repo for the `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`. So you need to install other distro packages. In this case, did used CentOS.

```
$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/hicolor-icon-theme-0.11-1.1.el6.noarch.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-1.30.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gdk-pixbuf2-2.24.1-6.el6_7.x86_64.rpm

$ sudo yum install ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/gtk2-2.24.23-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Once the packages are install the setup should work for you

PS: Source https://ubunifu.co/python/installing-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-in-amazon-linux-ami-2017-03-1

Answer (score 1):

I'm using chef but this is where I got the necessary dependencies.
just add this repo to yum repos, and then do the install

```
yum_repository 'centos-base' do
 url 'http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/'
 gpgkey 'http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6'
 action :add
end

package 'qt5-qtwebkit-devel'
```

Comment: I managed to install `qt5-qtwebkit-devel` using a variation of the above procedure, but  `gem install` still cannot find `qmake`.  Do you know where `qmake` would be installed?

Comment: upon install you should have qmake in /usr/bin/qmake-qt5, which I just symlink as qmake

Comment: Hmm.  No there and `which qmake-qt5` comes up empty.

Comment: I phrased that wrong in my last comment, you should see qmake-qt5 in /usr/bin as a file. qmake-qt5 isn't a directory. so even if you list the contents of /usr/bin you dont see any qmake-**** anything?

Comment: I didn't see anything because the install never completed.  Silly me.  I did finally get it to install using @Tarun's recommendation.  Thanks for your help.  This answer helped me add the centos mirror.

Comment: glad to help, they were pretty much the same thing. as long as centos repo and epel-release repo were enabled, doing yum install qt5-qtwebkit-devel. would have installed the qt webkit package with dependencies saving you from having to individually yum install the missing dependencies.

Comment: I tried both and the other one worked.  I am not sure why the centos mirror you recommended would not load `hicolor-icon-theme`